# Is reputation transfer possible?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, privileges

Is it possible to transfer my account reputation to anybody? If it is legal, how? Because if I want close or deleted my account.

Note:

If I deleted my account, what would happen to my account points, privileges and badges, etc.?

Comment: +1 for asking about this, since you suspected it might not be kosher - rather than just doing it.

Comment: While you can of course delete your account,  why do you want to? Why not just leave it unusued. Then if in a couple of years you want to come back it'll be here waiting for you

Comment: Also partial reputation transfer would be good. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50130/218314 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/218314

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your account is deleted, everything associated with it will be gone.

They will not be "transferred" to anyone and **shouldn't** be - reputation is a measure of how much the community trusts someone - if you didn't "earn" it, you shouldn't get it. Sometimes, when we delete accounts that were very active, we transfer votes and such to the community user, so the community itself doesn't get disrupted.

If you do feel like "transferring" reputation, offer bounties. But give them to posts who deserve it.

Comment: About bounties - if he will do it on his own questions and then delete his account, what will happen? I was thinking that it would take away bounty prizes from users who got them. If so, can you maybe warn OP that to effectively give away rep, he should do it on questions by others? And if I'm wrong, I'll be glad for a clarification / pointer.

Comment: @Mołot - Once the bounty has been given to someone, it has been given. I don't believe it will get removed even if the OP gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I believed it acts like votes, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @Dukeling - true enough. Answer updated.

Comment: What about [the mysterious Community user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/)? Doesn't it/she/he get any? That reference contains "Owns bounties from deleted users".

Comment: @Peter, I assume that means that if there is an open bounty when the user is deleted, Community ♦ takes over that bounty once the creator is gone.