# Can I transfer my reputation between Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I have seen that there are some questions about transferring rep to other people and there is obviously the bounty system for that.
What I want to know is if I can transfer my own reputation or somehow benefit from one site to another?

Comment: The bounty system is **NOT** a way of "transferring rep to other people".

Comment: The only reputation benefit from participating on another site is the well documented association bonus of 100.

Comment: There was a post that indicated that if you want to delete your account then that is one of the only ways you can make sure that your rep does not end up being lost. That sounds like a transfer to me.

Comment: If the users have written answers that you think deserve the reward of a bounty or you'd like to attract more attention to a question that needs it, you are more than welcome to use up your reputation in that way. I'd be interested in seeing this post because it's absolutely wrong to give all your rep to one person through bounties. If you're caught doing it, the bounties will be invalidated.

Comment: For reference, see [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208878/is-reputation-transfer-possible/208880#208880). Note the last sentence "But give them to posts who deserve it.".

Comment: @Catija - No one talked about giving all your rep to one person for no reason. I was referring to the exact same scenario, you award your bounty to someone because they deserve it and so what is wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing. But that is not a "transfer". People who ask about "transfers" want to give rep to their friend so that they can get past the low-reputation limits. That's not OK.

Comment: That is a generalization. It is a transfer of some sort just not what you are used to hearing about. There is no "people", there is just me asking a question and you commenting without understanding it. I have no intention of giving away my reputation and you should not be assuming. Just because I am a new user does not mean you should assume I am trying to cheat or something.

Comment: Because you are new I can not expect you to know that it **is** cheating. I'm telling you this in the hope that, in future, you will not make this mistake. There are many sites out there that allow such a thing, so we see many users who hope that it is also allowed here.

Comment: @Catija - now this is more like it. This is the explanation you should give me before any assumptions or downvotes for no reason. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, not directly.

The only exception is the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus).