# Asking good questions is hard. Answering questions is even harder!

Tags: discussion, reputation

Let's start with the assumption that all questions which receive upvotes are good. Yes, that's a terrible assumption, but it's about to get worse, so bear with me.

1. The questions which get tonnes of votes are, generally, not the questions which are hard to write. They are either very general questions (e.g. "how do i join too strings in python I don't know where the documentations are ples?") or very simple questions about everyday life which do not take any research.
2. Even if you consider a very well written question, which is the result of boatloads of work, or, as the article correctly says,

   > It requires thoughtfulness and an attention to how to best convey the issue you are having. You need to take a step back and pretend you are describing your problem to a total stranger that has no context around your situation. They aren’t seeing your compilation logs, and they don’t know what the feature you are building is, what libraries you are using, or what version of the framework is on your machine.

   an answer is *still* harder to write, irrespective of the accessibility of the question. Answers require thoughtfulness on your part about the problem to derive a solution. They need you to take a step back, assess the background of the OP, and provide all the context for their response. The OP hasn't taken the same classes as you, and hasn't worked in the same environment as you. They don't know the commands you're using to build your solution. They haven't used those concepts you propose.

   Most importantly, you're the one who's bringing the knowledge to the table. We're giving you rep because you're contributing that knowledge. We're giving the asker *some* rep because of their effort. If it were easy to ask questions, we wouldn't have given them rep at all.
3. It's part of a grand assumption that new users are askers. Sure, that's certainly the majority, but we want to give plenty of love to the new users who are coming here because they want to help people, or because they want to practice teaching people. And in their eyes (we're focusing on the whole thing of inclusion and being welcoming, so I'm not even considering veteran users here), this site gives just as many points to a person who's asking questions, and that is not compelling at all.
4. The change underestimates the role of good answers in making questions popular. There are several cases (arguably a majority of HNQs), particularly on science sites, where the question itself is a pretty boring but accessible one about everyday life or some well-publicized concept, but then receives a fantastic answer and ends up receiving tonnes of attention and votes. On many sites, HNQ visitors make up a plurality of voters, so do we really want these questions being rewarded just for getting good answers?
5. The wording of the change is just wrong. Period. "We're rewarding the question askers?" Seriously? You're making a huge divide between veteran users who answer questions and new users who ask questions, and although I won't deny the correlation between the number of years spent by a user on SE and the proportion of posts which are questions, I don't think that you should build features to specifically help individual groups because it doesn't foster the idea of all of us *sharing* knowledge as a single community.

Comment: @Skooba Not really. It's more like "we" think we have tonnes of pearls which are also available for free even when we try to abuse the oysters and now we want tonnes of sand because sand's really "in" these days and anyways we have so many pearls that the demographic is imbalanced.

Comment: (to be clear, sand is the poor questions which are now being given more reputation through votes. I'm not making fun of the idea of inclusivity, which is also very "in"; I believe that _that_ is something worth working towards, though SE hasn't done much on that front recently)

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked here; it seems like just a series of personal statements. What's the actual question? (The only thing I can parse out of it is if we think increasing the value of question upvotes is good. But that would be a duplicate of ["Should the weight of question upvotes be increased network-wide?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337843/389569)

Comment: @Orkin I fully agree. The site I know best ([TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)) is full of dumb “draw this for me” and “read the doc for me” questions that get upvotes because... well, just look at youtube and social networks in general. “Me too” effect, etc. Since this site only wants questions that can have “objective answers” (whatever wording they use) and since Management doesn't care about feedback on Meta as shown by the massive licence violation with no answer + unfair damage to Monica, maybe you should consider writing this kind of thing on Twitter?

Comment: You can spend days writing a clever answer that required a lot of knowledge and get between 0 and 4 upvotes (especially if you are caring about an oldish question no one dared approach before!). Meanwhile, many people write stupid questions, don't even bother to provide a minimal working example, and guess what? They routinely get like 6 to 10 upvotes. Rep was already kind of misleading due to robots always answering the same things and upvoting each other, but this change is going to completely destroy any legitimacy.

Comment: User [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) who wrote an insane amount of extremely knowledgeable and clever answers [never asked any question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=questions), he won't get anything from this change while people asking tons of dumb duplicates or “draw this for me” questions will get +1000 or so. This is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this goes as an answer, but I guess it might, so I'll let the community's votes tell me if it's appropriate and perhaps correct.

It may be that we're focusing on rep as an indicator of familiarity with site tools and policies, rather than of knowledge. This interpretation nullifies all qualms listed in the question, but it has its flaws. This is supported by the correlation between rep and moderation privileges (review queues etc, not the diamond tools). If you can ask good questions, you probably know your way around the help centers which help you do that, or you otherwise somehow have a good idea of how good questions should look, so you could be trusted with the ability to look at other peoples' posts and see if they're in line with what the system wants.

If this is the case, I feel that the article on the blog should explicitly state this, rather than the garbage it cites which clearly violates the spirit of optimizing for pearls, not sand, the principles behind which have not yet been conclusively proved to be obsolete.

Comment: If by "we" you mean Stack Exchange Corporate, "we" are focusing on rep as *an indicator of friendliness.*