# My reputation suddenly raised by 10k!

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation on Stack Overflow suddenly raised from 35k to 45k! And it seems that on other sites as well! It must have been in the past hour!

What happened? I don't see any record in the reputation history or jump in the chart, everything is just smooth! And it seems it happened on other sites as well!

I'm not complaining, just curious! :-)

**EDIT:** The discussion was "it was in the banner, you should have read it", and when I replied that I am closing banners without reading, and important announcements like that should be in the notification box, I got comments like "Oh yeah not reading banners is bad".

Now look at this and tell me: is anyone still surprised that I got used to closing banners without reading?? ;-)

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote your post. Please refer the blog post: [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

Comment: if there was a change so big, there should probably have been an anouncement...

Comment: @Tomas I first noticed this, as many others as well, due to a top-bar banner announcing this somewhat earlier on at least 2 sites I recall (math & I believe this one). Perhaps you did not get this?

Comment: Not sure whether you are received the banner or not in the top bar. At least I can see the banner in all the Stack Exchange sites https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq5zH.png

Comment: The banner, the blog, the blog announcement to the right of your question, etc. It has bee all over Meta. I'm not sure how you missed it.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to include any other add'l details you feel would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @RonMaupin Fairly easily to miss. The black banner at the top and the blog have been used frequently for all kinds of less interesting (to me) posts lately.  I regularly check the network and only caught the announcement earlier from Cody Gray's post on MSO.

Comment: Well, you wrote, "_if there was a change so big, there should probably have been an anouncement._" I was merely pointing out that it had been announced in multiple ways. I'm not sure what else could have been done.

Comment: @RonMaupin I'm not the OP, but personally I think it would help if site-changing announcements were visually distinguishable from interviews or guest posts on the blog about technologies I don't use.  Overusing banners makes them more ignorable.  If I remember right there used to be a way to make something in the bulletin stand out, like red text for major announcements that was used sparingly, but I don't know if it survived the redesign.  A global notification (like for mod elections) would be more visible too, as an example.

Comment: @Troyen exactly!! I instinctively close banners as annoying before reading (because they are rarely interesting), but I am reading all notifications! See my comment under Megan's answer.

Comment: There is a banner, all right, but as many other users I completely missed the announcement.

Comment: I thought it was an underline to the "don't use IE" banner.

Comment: Well if you dismiss all informative banners without even reading them then I'm not really sure what you expect... simply stop doing that?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica well if 99% of banners are not interesting for you than you hardly stop doing that... better to post such an important information in notification box.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Congrats! Yes. Upvotes on questions are now worth 10 points instead of 5 points and the change was applied retroactively across the network. [You can read more from us on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). It was also announced via a site banner and we sent emails to people with Stack Overflow accounts (due to technical limitations, we couldn't send to everyone across the network, unfortunately). Cody Gray also [wrote up a nice answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391247/what-was-the-context-of-the-decision-to-lower-the-value-of-upvotes-to-a-question/391248#391248) from his perspective as a moderator and community member which you may find helpful as well.

Comment: OK thanks! Sorry, so I probably closed the banner without reading - I instinctively close banners as annoying before reading (because they are rarely interesting), but I am reading all notifications! ^_^

Comment: Don't sweat it! I feel you. :)

Comment: thanks, no sweat - just an info on user behaviour ;-) :-D

Comment: I'm curious as to what sort of technical limitations restricted your ability to email users about this to SO?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica emails are sent via some server, which is hosted by some external company. Every company put some limit to emails that can be sent, sometimes it's 1k, sometimes 20k, but with millions of emails to send it means many days before all those emails are sent. Found a [nice post about it](https://blog.woodpecker.co/cold-email/email-sending-limits/)

Comment: @Shadow, I work in small company, and email is not our bread and butter. And yet we can send upwards 50-70k mails per day. I would imagine SO has significantly bigger pipes than us. But maybe I'm wrong

Comment: @yivi you might be using external campaign provider (not sure that's how it's called?), but SO send the emails all by themselves, so they're dependent on their host for the limits.

Comment: @Shadow SO uses sendgrid.com. (At least they did for **this** email). I'm using AWS. Same thing, in the end. The width of the pipe is mostly what you are willing to pay.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard And if the change hadn't been rushed out, there would have been plenty of time for that, just like every other company does. If you can send to everybody on SO, you can send to everybody on SE. Perhaps it'd cost more, perhaps it'd take longer .. but I don't buy the "we couldn't due to technical limitations" unless there's some _internal_ reason (database access, email addresses not stored for all sites, etc)