# Tour for SE: Question upvote score +5 is not updated to +10

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

#### [Tour page](https://stackexchange.com/tour)

> +5: question voted up

should be changed to +10 in light of [recent changes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/?cb=1).

[image: Cover page for SE: Question upvote score +5 is not updated to +10, as can be seen in the middle section.]
<sub><sub>**Source:** [SE Main Tour](https://stackexchange.com/tour)</sub></sub>

Comment: May be better to revert the changes as suggested by majority of answerers- see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337843/should-the-weight-of-question-upvotes-be-increased-network-wide

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A fix for this went out with the last build.

[image]

Surprisingly, pretty much all other code accounts for the dynamic nature of reputation rewards (even if this is the first exercise of that in years).  This one place is hard coded, probably because picking a value when it technically could vary per site is tricky AND `stackexchange.com` didn't use to share much code with the rest of the sites.